# How do you create curly hair with curves using the hair asset pack?

Tags: particles, hair

[image]

I'm designing a character with hair like this. He pretty much has little curls going in every direction. I would just like to know if there's a more efficient way to generate a bunch of hair curls without having to comb the hair curves individually.

Btw, I'm using hair curves in Blender 3.6. Is there anything I can use in their hair asset pack? Thank you.

Comment: We don't usually ask questions like "how to do this?" or "why doesn't it work?" here, please make your questions easy to understand and make sure that the question has not already been answered by someone else. 
You can also watch the official [Blender 3.5 Hair System Tutorial](https://youtu.be/_-d0HaT5f1g?si=sgXmM3Rdybx-F-AJ).

Comment: I have attached the .blend file to my answer so that you can test it to see if it matches the look you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Clump Hair Curves modifier in Blender 3.5's new hair system.

Select the Mesh, add an empty Hair, add the Generate Hair and Interpolate Hair modifiers, set the values your PC can handle.
Add the Clump Hair modifier and set its values.
To get a curly look, add the Curl Hair Curves modifier.

If you want to manually comb curves you need to apply the "Generate Hair Curves" modifier.

[image: Hair modifiers]
[image: Suzanne with hair curves]
[image]

Comment: I followed your instructions and got the EXACT look I was going for! Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad you found it helpful, you can combine different nodes to get more interesting results.